# how to extract two different pandas series element and map to rows in dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe in pandas which looks like this..

```
coupon_type     dish_id        dish_name  dish_price  dish_quantity
0     Rs 20 off       012      Sandwich      65            2
1     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125            3
2     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125            3
3     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125            3

        ratings         reviews  coupon_type  user_id order_id  meals 
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
3     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London  

     order_area
       London
       London
       London
       London
```

I am doing groupby on dish_name column.

```
df_dish_name = df_final.groupby('dish_name')
```

Then I am performing some ratio operations on groupby.

Which gives me following pandas series..which I am storing in `dish_specific_perf`

```
dish_name
 Chicken       45.000000
 Sandwich      61.111111
```

I have other ratio operation performed on groupby..

Which gives me following pandas series..which I am storing in `dish_relative_perf`

```
 dish_name
 Chicken       5.000000
 Sandwich      21.111111
```

Then I am checking one condition in an `if` statement..

```
if ((dish_specific_perf < 50).any() & (dish_relative_perf > 20).any() == True):
```

If the condition is true then, I want to add ("NP") string to corresponding dish name in dataframe.. So, In dataframe it should look like this.

```
      coupon_type     dish_id  dish_name   dish_price  dish_quantity
 0     Rs 20 off       012      Sandwich     65            2
 1     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
 2     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
 3     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3

ratings    reviews      coupon_type  user_id order_id  meals order_area
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
3     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London  

Flag
NP
NP
NP
NP
```

I am doing it with following code..

```
df_final['Flag'] = df_final['dish_name'].map(dish_relative_perf >20).map(dish_specific_perf < 50)
```

But it only evaluates first condition but not the condition on second series.
Is it because two different series will have different elements after if loop?

Comment: Hmm doesn't this work though: `df_final['Flag'] = df_final['dish_name'].map((dish_relative_perf >20) & (dish_specific_perf < 50))`?

Comment: it only evaluates first condition.. `i.e.(dish_relative_perf >20)`  doesn't evaluate second one.

Comment: I don't understand are you wanting logical and, or logical or here?

Comment: @EdChum I want logical and..

Comment: Well then your expected output is wrong, relative_perf is only > 20 for Sandwich and only Chicken has specific perf < 50 so it should be False for all entries

Comment: how can it be false? if relative_perf > 20 yields sandwich then it should set corresponding flag to np & if specific_perf <50 yields chicken the it should set corresponding flag to np

Comment: logical and requires both conditions to be satisfied, neither of those satisfy both conditions

Comment: It sounds like you want logical or: `df_final['Flag'] = df_final['dish_name'].map((dish_relative_perf >20) | (dish_specific_perf < 50))`

Comment: Yes, you are right..logical or is giving me correct results.. but I am still not clear because first condition will return true and even second will also return true.. so,and should work.. or I am mistaking somewhere?

Comment: Not according to your data, there is no row where both conditions are satisfied